# File import 2 variables from same line

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to import from phase-1.txt to a 2d array such that each line in the file will place 2 variables for each row of the array (A String, An int)

```
public class Simulation {
    ArrayList fileOne;

    public ArrayList loadItem() throws Exception {

        File phaseOne = new File("phase-1.txt");
        fileOne = new ArrayList();
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(phaseOne);
        while (scanner1.hasNextLine()) {
            fileOne.add(scanner1.nextLine());
        }
        return fileOne;
    }

    public ArrayList getFileOne() {
        return fileOne;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK so what is your question?

Comment: considering each line in file contains a string and int (for eg. `test 123`), you can store it as a combined String in the list and when accessing, split it and cast it in respective types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a type....

```
public class Simulation {
    ArrayList fileOne;

    public ArrayList loadItem () throws Exception{

        File phaseOne = new File("phase-1.txt");
        fileOne = new ArrayList<FileRow>();
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(phaseOne);
        while(scanner1.hasNextLine()){
            fileOne.add(new FileRow(scanner1.nextLine()));
        }
       return fileOne;
    }

    public ArrayList getFileOne() {
        return fileOne;
    }

}

class FileRow{
    String stringValue;
    int intValue;

    FileRow(String fileRowString){
        String [] splitString = fileRowString.split("=");
        this.stringValue = splitString[0];
        this.intValue = splitString[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi osoblanco, I've tried you method but I it didn't fully work as my file line look something like that (building tools=3000) so I need to split the line by the equal sign such that everything before the equal should fall under the string and everything after it should fall in the integer value.

Comment: I updated solution to address this additional info.  Meanwhile, if it's a true equals relationship without duplicate strings, and order doesn't matter I would do this in a map instead of creating the FileRow type.

Comment: thank you osoblanco :) much appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you need something like:

```
public void readFile() throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Object[]> rows = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("phase-1.txt"));
    String line;
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String words[] = line.split("\\s+");
        String first = words[0];
        int second = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
        rows.add(new Object[] {first, second});
    }
    Object[][] finalRows = new Object[rows.size()][];//2d array
    rows.toArray(finalRows);
}
```

For the array you could use something like ArrayList or Object[][]

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for sharing your answer. I need to add to a 2d arraylist but I've never used bufferedreader before. how can I get the size of (in) to help fill up the array.

Comment: If you don't know how many lines from the file, then you can really only find out by reading the whole file.  So instead you can just use a List that grows as needed.  I am updating the answer.

Comment: Thank you Sean, the solution works well